# How does BroadcastReceiver work belong to app state?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

My question is about behavior of Receivers when app is 'Died' - does receivers die also with it, or they are still working in memory?

My problem is about such situation - I can't listen action 'App is destroyed' and carefully do 'unregisterReciever'. **So i want to know - what happens with receivers in memory belong to app state.**

PS - approachs like doing unregister in 'onstop' of Activity doesn't fit to my situation.

Comment: Maybe provide some code to explain which problem you are facing. And read the the docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: @finki - I have broadcast receiver, which I need to unregister when app is died \closed etc. But I can't listen this event 'clear', so I want to know - if the receiver is running and app is closed - will receiver die too. I read LOT OF official documentation and no information about this were found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ! The behaviour of whether the receiver will die/destroy (In terms of execution) depends upon the type of receiver you are registering. If you are registering your BroadcastReceiver in app Manifest `Manifest-declared receivers` then after the app is closed BroadcastReceivers don't die as Official documentation says.

> The system creates a new BroadcastReceiver component object to handle
>   each broadcast that it receives. This object is valid only for the
>   duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code
>   returns from this method, the system considers the component no longer
>   active.
>
> If you declare a broadcast receiver in your manifest, the system
>   launches your app (if the app is not already running) when the
>   broadcast is sent.

The Other type of BroadcastRecievers is `Context-registered receivers`.
Context-registered receivers are those receivers that:

> receive broadcasts as long as their registering context is valid. For
>   an example, if you register within an Activity context, you receive
>   broadcasts as long as the activity is not destroyed

in that case when the context of the linked component is destroyed then `BroadcastReciever` will also be destroyed.

Comment: But make sure in and after Oreo most of the implicit broadcast receivers  wont work.

Comment: @finki why are you so rude? If YOU want to ANSWER this question you can write this parts from article. And yes, I didn't see this parts in the article from google developers when I reading it.

Comment: I just want to encourage android newcomers to actually read the docs. as i see the same questions over and over again. I'm not rude. I'm just trying to save your and our time here. If you get deeper into android development you will actually have to read the documentation way more carefully (background services e.g.)